# Context-sensitive help for menu items in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, context-sensitive-help

I am implementing context-sensitive help for an existing WinForms app built in Visual Studio .NET. I have added a `HelpProvider` to the form and set the `HelpNamespace` property to a wonderful `.chm` that covers every control and menu item on the form. I have set the necessary `HelpKeyword` on all the controls that derive from `Control` and so far all is great: F1 works perfectly.

My problem is that I can't work out how to do it for menu items. These use the `ToolStripMenuItem` class, which does not derive from `Control` and so has no `HelpKeyword` property. How should I provide context-sensitive help for individual menu items? Mr. Google has not been very forthcoming.

Comment: If you are going to make `F1` key working for `ToolStripMenuItem` elements, then you should rely on `HelpRequested` event of form. Also you should set `ShowHelp` extended property to `false` for all controls and show help yourself using `Help` class. Also keep help keywords for menu items in their `Tag` or using a new extender provider.

Comment: @RezaAghaei thanks but there is no HelpRequested event for the ToolStripMenuItem class. I guess I could use the HelpRequested event that fires for the MenuStrip but would need to work out which menu item has been clicked from the Mouse position. It seems to me that there should be an easier way, surely this is a common thing to want to do?

Comment: Using `F1` is not a common way of providing help for menu items. Menu items usually use tooltip, or show some text help in statusbar or usually their comprehensive helps comes with help of main page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using <kbd>F1</kbd> is not a common way of providing help for menu items. Menu items usually use *ToolTip*, or show some help text in *StatusBar* or usually their comprehensive helps comes with *Help content of main page*.

*I prefer to use one of above mentioned solutions, but here for learning purpose, I'll show what you can do using [`HelpRequested`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.helprequested?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) event of the form.*

To handle help for form and controls, you can rely on the [`HelpRequested`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.helprequested?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) event of the form and controls.

Here you can rely on `Form` event to solve the problem. Since you have a [`HelpProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.helpprovider?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) on form, you should know `HelpProvider` handles `HelpRequested` event of all controls internally and, for controls having `ShowHelp` set to `true`, it sets `Handled` to `true` and prevents bubbling the event up so you can not have your custom code for handling help event if `ShowHelp` is `true`. So you should set `ShowHelp` for controls to `false` and just use `HelpProvider` as a help key holder.

To solve the problem using the `HelpRequested` event of the form, you should follow these steps:

1. For `ToolStripMenuItems`, use the `Tag` property as the help key holder.
2. For other controls, if you use `HelpProvider` to assign `HelpKey`, don't forget to set `ShowHelp` to `false`.
3. Handle the `HelpRequested` event of the form.
4. In the body of event handler, check if there is an active menu item on your form, then use the `Tag` property of the active item to show help. If there is not any active menu, use the `ActiveControl` property of the form to show the help.

**Example**

Here is a step by step example of how you can show help for menu items using <kbd>F1</kbd> key. To do so, follow these steps:

1. **Create Form, Menu and Controls** - Create a `Form` and put some controls and a `MenuStrip` having some menu and sub menus on the form.
2. **Configuring HelpProvider** - Put a `HelpProvider` control on form and for each control assign suitable key to `HelpKeyword` property of control. Also set `ShowHelp` for each control to false. We will handle help in code.
3. **Configuring Help for Menu** - For a `ToolStripMenuItem` use its `Tag` property to store the help keyword.
4. **Creating a helper method to find descendants of the Menu** - Add a class to your application having the following code. In the following code, I've introduced an extension method to get all sub `ToolStripMenuItem` of a `MenuStrip`:

   ```
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Windows.Forms;
   public static class ToolStripMenuItemExtensions
   {
       public static List<ToolStripMenuItem> Descendants(this MenuStrip menu)
       {
           var items = menu.Items.OfType<ToolStripMenuItem>().ToList();
           return items.SelectMany(x => Descendants(x)).Concat(items).ToList();
       }
       public static List<ToolStripMenuItem> Descendants(this ToolStripMenuItem item)
       {
           var items = item.DropDownItems.OfType<ToolStripMenuItem>().ToList();
           return items.SelectMany(x => Descendants(x)).Concat(items).ToList();
       }
   }
   ```
5. **Handling the Helprequested event to show help** - Handle the `HelpRequested` event of the form and implement the algorithm which I described above using the following code:

   ```
   private void Form1_HelpRequested(object sender, HelpEventArgs hlpevent)
   {
       string keyword = "";

       var selectedMenuItem = this.menuStrip1.Descendants()
           .Where(x => x.Selected).FirstOrDefault();
       if (selectedMenuItem != null)
           keyword = selectedMenuItem.Tag?.ToString();
       else if (ActiveControl != null)
           keyword = helpProvider1.GetHelpKeyword(ActiveControl);

       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
           Help.ShowHelp(this, "Help.chm", HelpNavigator.Index, keyword);
   }
   ```

**Note**

- For testing the solution you don't need a chm file having index and so on. You can simply show the helpkeyword in `Text` property of form. It means the solution is working and after that you can create suitable chm file.
- You can use one of the other overloads of `ShowHelp` method of [`Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.help?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) class based on your requirement.
- There are `HelpKeyword` and `HelpString` extended properties for controls, pay attention which one you are using and get the same one in the `HelpRequested` event.
- Don't forget to set `ShowHelp` to false. If you forget this step, the event will be handled internally in `Helpprovider`.
- Don't forget to assign a help keyword to `Tag` property of menu items. To make it more friendly for future, you can simply create an extender provider that adds a help keyword property to menu items.

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the effort! I was just in the process of trying to work out which menu item was selected in the event handler and you have saved me some time. I also didn't realise that turning off the ShowHelp property is what enables the HelpRequested event to fire when a HelpProvider is present. I can confirm that this works with a couple of tweaks for my usage. BTW the help file was already written by our doc group and it has some nice graphics etc., that's why I don't want to use a plain text ToolTip or the status bar. Thanks again :-)

Comment: @JonP Great! You're welcome and thanks for the edit :)